# MySQL Performance Planning

Tags: mysql, performance

I am considering moving my existing script which is downloaded to be a hosted script.  One of the things it does is to keep track of some stats.  My concern is with heavy hitters (100,000 pageviews/month on up), it might tax my mysql process.

I'm currently using a VPS, which would be just to start with.  My question is...

How do I best plan ahead for an easy/smooth transition to another mysql server if load gets too high?

Thanks for any advice, it's appreciated.

Comment: Let's put things into perspective. 100k page views per month is .039 page views per second: (100,000 / 30) / 84,600 = 0.0394011032 In other words, one page view per 25 seconds. Why exactly do you think you need to worry about this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out first what makes the load get too high so that you are able to plan ahead.

If its IO bound then you need faster disks. If its memory bound then you need to add more memory or find ways to reduce its usage.

The best way to find out what the problem is, is to track your system during a peak time. Get a graphing application and look for:

- Hard disk usage
- CPU usage
- Memory usage
- Swap usage
- Raid card, if you have one

Also keep track of your `SHOW STATUS` info and see what are the differences. Try to notice patterns, find the bottlenecks and predict scalability issues.

For example, if you system is currently doing 100,000 transactions per minute and your bottlenecks are at 75% capacity, then if your TPM increase it to 140,000 your system might crash/stall/lagg/die-a-horrible-death.

Comment: Thanks - Yea I got rrdtool.  I'll keep this list in mind.